# Attempting window.location or window.location.href redirect which is causing a loop

Tags: javascript, html

I'm attempting to use javascript to determine if the user is using a certain language and if they're not using english then for the page to load a different page BUT with the params of which I've grabbed from the url.

I have been able to load the page with the params but I keep falling into a loop reloading the page, even after skimming through the countless other examples, such as: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2092090/page-re-load-refresh-after-javascript-alert-dont-want-it-do) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13683826/jquery-window-location-replace-keeps-looping).

```
function locateUserLanguage() {

    var languageValue = (navigator.languages ? navigator.languages[0] : (navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage)).split('-');

        var url = window.location.href.split('?');
        var baseUrl = url[0];
        var urlParams = url[1];


    if (languageValue[0] === 'en') {

        console.log('no redirect needed, stay here.');

    } else {


        // I tried to set location into a variable but also wasn't working.
        // var newURL = window.location.href.replace(window.location.href, 'https://www.mysite.dog/?' + urlParams);


        window.location.href = 'https://www.mysite.dog/?' + urlParams
    }

} locateUserLanguage();
```

I've attempted to place a `return true;` as well as `return false;` but neither stop the loop.

I've tried `window.location.replace();`  and setting the `window.location.href` straight to what I need, but it's continuing to loop.

Comment: what do you mean by "loop" here? Do you mean it's continuously reloading the same page? Is the URL this page is served at the same as the one you're redirecting to (`https://www.mysite.dog/`)?

Comment: Yeah, reloading the page. Apologies.  I mean that. The url i'm on when testing is localhost and is different than the site i'm asking it to load.  I take the params from the localhost page and attach them to the mysite.dog page.

Comment: What do you want to happen when you load the page with parameters? 
There is no check anywhere that checks if there are parameters and so you don't do anything with them.

Comment: Once it loads to the page with the parameters that it has brought with it, just to stay there.  It's loading a different page in another language and just want the parameters due to another function reading those parameters for another use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a possibility that the script in which this function is written is executed in both of your pages (english and non-english) on load. So, as soon as the page is loaded, locateUserLanguage function is executed in both english and non-english website causing the infinite loop.

You need to put a check before you call locateUserLanguage function.

Suppose english website has url = "www.myside.com" and non-english website has url "www.myside.aus". So the condition needs to be

```
if (window.location.host === "www.myside.com") { locateUserLanguage() }
```

This will make sure that locateUserLanguage is called only in english website.

Or other apporach can be to load this script only in english website which will avoid the usage of conditional statement.

Hope it helps. Revert for any doubts.

Comment: I put in the conditional at the top before the locateUserLanguage function runs but it still tries to continuous loop.  I'm wondering if there's something else happening that isn't easily seen.  

Part of the problem with second part is the script would be on the main page, landing, and therefore it needs to run because it isn't not english then it needs to go somewhere.  Hmmm continuing to look.  Appreciate the response.

Comment: Just to be sure, try putting console.log in your else part also (just before you do window.location.href and see in console if the logging happens. If logging happens, then it means issue it with the function getting called repeatedly otherwise issue will be somewhere else.

Comment: Sorry I should have put that in yesterday but yes, it does run the console log in the else statement.  So it seems it may be calling repeatedly.  Which I'm trying to figure out how to stop it from doing that.  I thought returning true; would do it but seems not.

Comment: I'm thinking it has to do with the page I was rerouting to.   I've changed it for testing to my dir path and it seems to be not looping. Which makes me believe it was a matter of routing from my localhost to the page when testing locally, it's not happening....

I'm still testing to make sure but will let you know.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure if it was the site I was navigating to was causing the problem or not but I ended up putting in a check at the beginning before running anything else doing what you suggesting so i'm putting your answer as the correct as it was something I needed to stop any other looping from helping.  Thanks. Appreciate it.